# Getting text from <td> element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if (document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML == "word"){
      $("td:first").html("another word");
}
```

I just want to check if this  have this text .

Answer (score 3):

You mean

```
if($('#td1').text() === "word"){
   $("td:first").html("another word");
}
```

this matches `<div id=td1>word</div>`

Comment: Even better: `$("td:first").text("another word");`. Given the example, I don't think the OP wants to insert mark-up.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario the OP included the code in the question - this answer hasn't changed that code at all !

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#td1:contains('word')").html("another word");
```

[Test](http://fiddle.jshell.net/JkA7A/)

Comment: @M.z yes but this would be true also if the text is `lessword` or any other textthat contains `word`